# C# code to run weka Classifier using IKVM.net and WEKA.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, weka, data-mining, ikvm

l am using same code in C# (visual studio 2017) and  am have  included IKVM.OpenJDK.*.dll (last version )and weka.dll in project

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            class_test(); 
        }

const int percentSplit = 60;
        public void class_test()
        {
            string resualt = "";

            try
            {

                 weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("iris.arff"));



                insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1); 

                weka.classifiers.Classifier cl = new weka.classifiers.trees.J48();    // choose type of classifer algorithms 

                int trainSize = insts.numInstances() * percentSplit / 100;
                int testSize = insts.numInstances() - trainSize;
                weka.core.Instances train = new weka.core.Instances(insts, 0, trainSize);

                cl.buildClassifier(train);
                int numCorrect = 0;
                for (int i = trainSize; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
                {
                    weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
                    double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
                    if (predictedClass == insts.instance(i).classValue())
                        numCorrect++;
                }

                System.Console.WriteLine(numCorrect + " out of " + testSize + " correct (" +
                    (double)((double)numCorrect / (double)testSize * 100.0) + "%)");
            }
            catch (java.lang.Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But i am getting the following errors:

first :

> The type Reader is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add a reference assembly 'vislib, Version=1.0.5000.0,
>   Cultureneutral PublicKey Token-b0315f7f11d50a3a choose

on the line :

```
weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("iris.arff"));
```

on

```
new weka.core.Instances
```

second :

> Argument 1 : cannot convert from 'java.io.FileReader' to
>   'weka.core.instances

on the same line :

```
weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("iris.arff"));
```

on

```
(new java.io.FileReader("iris.arff"));
```

to solve the second error, i tried to add Ikvm.GUN.classpath.dll for another older version as reference, But i am getting the following error:

> The type FileReader exists in both 'IKVM.GNU.Classpath, Version=
>   0.12.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKey Token13235d27fcbfff58 and 'IKVM.Open/DK.Core Version=7.2.4630.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKey
>   Token: 13235d271cbfff58

please, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the output warning messages after  the execution of .dll generation command, if you see something like this, i.e.:

***warning IKVMC0108: Not a class file "weka/core/Instances.class", including it as resource (class format error "52.0")***

then IKVM Java version is not aligned with the weka.jar build version

you can download the java 8 version of IKVM here: http://www.frijters.net/ikvmbin-8.1.5717.0.zip